# Positive sectional curvature does not imply positive definite curvature operator?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

The curvature operator on $\Lambda^2(TM)$ is defined on decomposable bivectors by $$g(\mathfrak{R}(X \wedge Y), V \wedge W) = R(X,Y,W,V)$$ and then extended by linearity to all elements of $\Lambda^2(TM)$. It is self-adjoint, so defines a symmetric bilinear form on $\Lambda^2(TM)$. If this form is positive definite, then all sectional curvatures are positive.

My question is: are there Riemannian manifolds with positive sectional curvature but with an indefinite curvature operator?

Positive sectional curvature means that $g(\mathfrak{R}(\alpha), \alpha) > 0$ for all *decomposable* bivectors, which does not seem to exclude the existence of an *indecomposable* bivector $\beta$ for which $g(\mathfrak{R}(\beta), \beta) < 0$. In dimension 3 all bivectors are decomposable, so counterexamples can exist only starting from dimension 4.

A second question: If the answer to the previous question is "yes", what pinching of the sectional curvature does imply the positivity of the curvature operator?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For the first question: positive curvature operator on a compact manifold implies that the manifold is diffeomorphic to a space form, i.e., a manifold of sectional curvature one. This is due to C. Boehm and B. Wilking [Manifolds with positive curvature operators are space forms](http://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/annals-v167-n3-p10.pdf) Annals of Mathematics, 167 (2008), 1079–1097.

Thus most known positively curved manifolds do not admit metrics with positive curvature operator. The simplest example is $CP^n$, $n>1$.

I do not know know much about how sectional curvature pinching can imply positive curvature operator but for example, you could trace references from J.-P. Bourguignon, H. Karcher,  [Curvature operators: pinching estimates and geometric examples](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1978_4_11_1_71_0.pdf) in Ann. Sci. École Norm. Sup. (4) 11 (1978), no. 1, 71–92 where some estimates on the eigenvalues of the curvature operator in terms of sectional curvature pinching can be found.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer to the first question is even stronger than I expected: *any* metric on $CP^n$ has an indefinite curvature operator. For example for the Fubini-Study metric (that has sectional curvatures between 1 and 4) one can find a bivector on which the curvature operator is negative definite.

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev To the best of my knowledge, symmetric spaces of compact type have nonnegative curvature operator. On the level of Lie algebras, the symmetric form on $\Lambda^2TM$ associated with the curvature operator is $\langle[-,-],[-,-]\rangle$. Conversely, nonnegative curvature operator implies that all harmonic differential forms are parallel. Then $M$ is homeomorphic to a sphere, biholomorphic to complex proejctive space, quaternionic Kähler, or symmetric of compact type. References are [here, Rem 7](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2011-363-01/S0002-9947-2010-04878-0/home.html)

Comment: @SebastianGoette: thanks! So, the curvature operator of the Fubini-Study metric is positive semidefinite. I wonder if one can slightly deform the metric so that the operator becomes indefinite, but the scalar curvature remains positive.

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev Yes, you can. You just have to violate the Kähler condition with a small deformation of the Riemannian metric. By continuity, scalar curvature remains positive for small deformations. By [Cao-Chow](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01394422), destroying Kähler makes the curvature operator indefinit.

Answer (score 13):

Positive-definiteness of the curvature operator ($R>0$) is as **much** stronger condition than positive sectional curvature ($\sec>0$). In fact, as Igor mentions, it follows from the work of Boehm and Wilking that only spherical space forms admit metrics with $R>0$, while many (but not so many!) other manifolds admit metrics with $\sec>0$. An almost complete list of such manifolds can be found in Section 4 of this [survey of Ziller](https://www.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewziller/papers/survey_noneg_curvature_Final.pdf).

Of course, what happens is that although $R\colon\wedge^2 T_pM\to\wedge^2 T_pM$ is symmetric (hence diagonalizable), its eigenspaces need not intersect the Grassmannian $Gr_2(T_pM)=\{\sigma\in\wedge^2 T_pM:\sigma\wedge\sigma=0,\|\sigma\|=1\}$. Hence $R$ could have some zero (or even negative) eigenvalues at the same time as the restriction $\sec(\sigma)=\langle R(\sigma),\sigma\rangle$ of its quadratic form to $Gr_2(T_pM)$ is positive. For example, in $\mathbb C P^n$ this is what happens: $R$ is positive-semidefinite (and has nontrivial kernel), but this kernel does not intersect the Grassmannian.

---

Algebraically, there is an *intermediate* curvature condition between $\sec>0$ and $R>0$ called *strongly positive curvature*, that might be of interest to you. Namely, a curvature operator $R\colon\wedge^2 V\to\wedge^2 V$ has strongly positive curvature if there exists a $4$-form $\omega\in\wedge^4V$ such that $R+\omega$ is positive-definite. Here, $\omega\in\wedge^4 V$ is identified with a symmetric endomorphism $\omega\colon\wedge^2V\to\wedge^2V$ via $$\langle\omega(\alpha),\beta\rangle=\langle\omega,\alpha\wedge\beta\rangle.$$
Clearly, $R>0$ implies strongly positive curvature (take $\omega=0$).
Since $\sec(\sigma)=\langle R(\sigma),\sigma\rangle$ and $\langle\omega(\sigma),\sigma\rangle=\langle\omega,\sigma\wedge\sigma\rangle=0$ if $\sigma$ is decomposable, strongly positive curvature implies $\sec>0$. Together with R. Mendes, over the last years, I have pursued a systematic study of this curvature condition; see the following for details:

*Bettiol, Renato G.; Mendes, Ricardo A. E.*, [**Strongly positive curvature**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10455-017-9578-9), Ann. Global Anal. Geom. 53, No. 3, 287-309 (2018). [ZBL1395.53058](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1395.53058). [(arXiv)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.2117)

*Bettiol, Renato G.; Mendes, Ricardo A. E.*, [**Strongly nonnegative curvature**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00208-016-1457-3), Math. Ann. 368, No. 3-4, 971-986 (2017). [ZBL1377.53020](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1377.53020). [(arXiv)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07899)

*Bettiol, Renato G.; Mendes, Ricardo A. E.*, [**Flag manifolds with strongly positive curvature**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00209-015-1464-1), Math. Z. 280, No. 3-4, 1031-1046 (2015). [ZBL1360.53056](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1360.53056). [(arXiv)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.0039)

For example, $(\mathbb C P^n,g_{FS})$ has strongly positive  curvature, since $R+\varepsilon (\omega_{FS}\wedge\omega_{FS})>0$ for small $\varepsilon>0$, where $\omega_{FS}$ is the Fubini-Study $2$-form.

The upshot is that almost all known examples of manifolds with $\sec>0$ actually satisfy this much stronger condition. For manifolds with $\sec\geq0$, actually *all* known examples satisfy the analogous "strongly nonnegative curvature" condition (which requires $R+\omega$ to be positive-semidefinite).

Comment: Renato, has there been anything on positive pinching vs positive curvature operator after the paper of Bourguignon and Karcher I linked to?

Comment: @Igor: not that I am aware of... Also Werner Ballmann asked me a few months ago whether strongly positive curvature could be seen as an intermediate pinching. But, just like the case for the curvature operator, there doesn't seem to be too much one can say.

Comment: @Renato: what is an example of a manifold with positive sec and curvature operator with some negative eigenvalues?

Comment: @RenatoG.Bettiol: Isn't "strongly nonnegative curvature" or "strongly positive curvature" an obvious definition that at least from top view is a useless tool? To me it is like this that I have a negative number in mind and you are seeking for a positive number that has a positive or nonnegative result when add up to my number. Why should this be a useful tool?

Comment: @CarloMantegazza: Any manifold with sec>0 whose universal cover is not isometric to a product of (i) Euclidean space, (ii) sphere with metric of positive-semidef curvature operator, (iii) compact irreducible symm space, (iv) compact Kaehler mfld biholomorphic to $CP^n$ with positive-semidef curature operator on (1,1)-forms. For example, the Wallach flag manifolds $W^6$, $W^{12}$, $W^{24}$, which are even homogeneous (see e.g. Ziller's survey Sec 4: https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wziller/papers/survey_noneg_curvature_Final.pdf) [Sorry for the super late answer!!]

Comment: @C.F.G: Some definitions might be more obvious to some of us :) In my opinion, this is an interesting and useful definition because it is algebraically very natural (some reasons are given in Thm B in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.03713.pdf cf. the difference between nonnegative polynomials and polynomials which are sums of squares), sits strictly between a class of manifolds still poorly understood (sec>0) and one completely classified (pos-def curvature operator), and was crucially used to produce the latest example in the former class (https://arxiv.org/abs/0809.2304). [Sorry for late reply!]

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/390636/90655

Answer (score 1):

This argument is due to Burkhard Wilking. The other answers, answer to the OP question very well but I want to give a sharp example. I.e. a manifold with positive sectional curvature and  curvature operator with some negative eigenvalues:

$$\exists\ (M,g)\ \text{s.t.}\ \sec_g>0\quad  \text{but not}\quad \ \mathcal{R}\geq0.$$

**Any** positive sectional curvature metric on $\mathsf{SU(3)}/\mathsf{T^2}$ has some  negative curvature operator. To see this. note that it is an irreducible simply connected Riemannian manifold of positive sectional curvature and [it is not diffeomorphic to any symmetric space](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4108931/272127); it follows that it should have some negative curvature operator by [classification of closed manifolds of nonnegative curvature operator](https://mathoverflow.net/q/390603/90655). See for instance [Page 270, theorem 7.34](https://books.google.com/books?id=dQYPCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA270#v=onepage&q&f=false) of

*Chow, Bennett; Lu, Peng; Ni, Lei*, **Hamilton’s Ricci flow**, Graduate Studies in Mathematics 77. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 0-8218-4231-5/hbk). xxxvi, 608 p. (2006). [ZBL1118.53001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1118.53001).