# Closed manifolds of nonnegative curvature operator are symmetric spaces

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, symmetric-spaces

In an online webinar, I heard (not directly) the statement  that **(closed) manifolds of nonnegative curvature operator $\mathcal{R}\geq 0$ are symmetric spaces**. Is this a valid theorem? Any reference that contains its proof? I am not sure that in the above statement whether "positive curvature" is a part of assumptions or not.

So by the above claim, it seems that $\mathcal{R}\geq 0\iff$ $M$ is symmetric space!

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/a/264899/3948 seems relevant.

Comment: If you slightly deform the standard metric on the unit sphere, you get a metric if positive curvature operator which is not symmetric. The same will happen if you slightly deform a spherical space form. Are you asking if all closed manifolds of nonnegative curvature operator are diffeomorphic to locally symmetric spaces?

Comment: @WillieWong: my question is different from that linked MO.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek: I am not sure, but I think so: "all closed manifolds of nonnegative curvature operator are diffeomorphic to _locally_ symmetric spaces?" Someone argued non rigorously  like this: a  nonnegative curvature operator is of positive curvature operator or its holonomy is not of full rank. Does this help to figure out what is the right statement?

Comment: Yes, I think closed irreductible manifolds of nonnegative curvature operator are diffeomorphic to locally symmetric spaces, see e.g. section 2.4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.07899.pdf.

Comment: @C.F.G ... hence a comment, just the mention that it is relevant, and not a vote to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Igor Belegradek commented, the correct statement is as follows:

> **Theorem (classification of closed simply connected manifold with nonnegative curvature operator):** A closed simply connected manifold with nonnegative curvature operator is isometric to a Riemannian product of
>
> 1. standard spheres with metrics of nonnegative curvature operator
> 2. closed Kahler manifolds biholomorphic to complex projective spaces whose
>    Kahler metric has nonnegative curvature operator on real (1, 1)-forms
> 3. *compact irreducible Riemannian symmetric spaces* with their natural
>    metrics of nonnegative curvature operator.

---

See for instance [Page 270, theorem 7.34](https://books.google.com/books?id=dQYPCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA270#v=onepage&q&f=false) of

*Chow, Bennett; Lu, Peng; Ni, Lei*, **Hamilton’s Ricci flow**, Graduate Studies in Mathematics 77. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS) (ISBN 0-8218-4231-5/hbk). xxxvi, 608 p. (2006). [ZBL1118.53001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1118.53001).

So closed simply connected irreducible manifolds of nonnegative curvature operator are isometric to locally symmetric spaces.

Comment: Your conclusion should be _diffeomorphic_, not _isometric_, because of Igor's comment (small deformations of the standard metric on the sphere give metric with positive curvature operator which are not locally symmetric).

Comment: @JeffreyCase: I see, but above theorem says that "is isometric to" .

Comment: The first case (with the irreducible assumption) is a manifold diffeomorphic to a sphere equipped with a metric whose curvature operator is nonnegative.  These do not have to be locally symmetric (i.e. $\nabla R$ need not vanish).

Comment: @JeffreyCase: I am not sure about the statement and I just quoted it from the books and papers. Fell free to correct the post.

Comment: @JeffreyCase I believe it is correct to write "isometric to" because the ambiguity in the metric restricts to the factors and is covered by the phrasing of 1 and 2 ("standard sphere" meaning "non-exotic").